# Change color of bar on hover in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I want to use *plotly* in R to make the following histogram change color to white on hover and to blue when clicked:

```
ggplotly(
  ggplot(iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram()
)
```

I found this great post on applying this to a scatterplot but I'm not sure how to "translate" it into my histogram: https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#hover-event but this doesn't work....

```
ggplotly(
  ggplot(iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram()
) %>%
htmlwidgets::onRender("
    function(el) { 
    console.log(el)
      el.on('plotly_hover', function(data){
  var pn='',
      tn='',
      colors=[];
  for(var i=0; i < data.points.length; i++){
    pn = data.points[i].pointNumber;
    tn = data.points[i].curveNumber;
    colors = data.points[i].data.marker.color;
  };
  colors[pn] = '#C54C82';
    
  var update = {'marker':{color: colors}};
  Plotly.restyle(el.id, update, [tn]);
});
      el.on('plotly_unhover', function(data){
  var pn='',
      tn='',
      colors=[];
  for(var i=0; i < data.points.length; i++){
    pn = data.points[i].pointNumber;
    tn = data.points[i].curveNumber;
    colors = data.points[i].data.marker.color;
  };
  colors[pn] = '#00000';
  var update = {'marker':{color: colors}};
  Plotly.restyle(el.id, update, [tn]);
});
    }
  ")
```